# Actionscript 2 : Custom Interval Function

Tags: timer, actionscript, setinterval, actionscript-2, intervals

I Been messing with Actionscript 2 for about 2 days.. And i have not learned much as im blindly going along with it... But i wrote a function and im curious as to why its not working.. So can someone tell me whats wrong with this code , or even if it could work?

```
function Interval(Funct:Function, Seconds:Number, Duration:Number){
var MyInterval:Number;
Seconds = Seconds * 1000;
MyInterval = setInterval(Funct, Seconds, Duration);
if(Seconds >= Duration * 1000)
{
    clearInterval(MyInterval);
}
return MyInterval;
}
```

Problem Solved , Solution Below :

```
function Interval(Funct:Function, Seconds:Number){
Seconds = Seconds * 1000;
_global.i = setInterval(Funct, Seconds);
}
```

Even though i did want a limit as to when it would stop if specified , im okay with this for now

Thank you [Ali-o-kan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2894092/ali-o-kan)

Edit : Ran into another problem with this function.. Whenever i enable it more than once using different keys , it leaves it on while creating more whenever i press the button again.. Any way to fix this?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this code? Where Duration and Seconds come from? Could you show how this function is used ?

Comment: I'm new to AS2 but pretty much the function works like this `Interval(MyFunction, 10, 30);` so in the actual code you can see setInterval(Funct, Seconds, Duration); which i believe i seen something about Duration being a normal parameter in setInterval so pretty much all im trying to do is make a simple code that uses setInterval but uses real seconds instead of milliseconds , the flash file im working on i want most of it to be like custom easier to use code so i want to use this code in a code for an onKeyDown

Comment: So how setInterval uses its parameters as setInterval(Function, interval); Mine just multiplies the interval by 1000 allowing me to type in 1 for 1 second instead of 1000

Comment: but  i dont get no errors it just doesnt run lol

Comment: I Did just find one area i messed up in when clearing the interval but the main problem is it doesnt start

Comment: First of all, add trace('hello'); in your function Interval to see if it is executed. What I think, is that `Seconds >= Duration * 1000` is all the time false.

Comment: You can find a good explanation and example on setInterval : https://www.kirupa.com/developer/actionscript/setinterval2.htm

Comment: i did trace when ran and it didnt trace anything out , but then again i havnt tried trace in the program im using , i tried using just a key to trace and then nothing came up in the output .. Im Using Sothing Swf Quicker to Develop in AS2

Comment: Okay , somehow i just got it to work.. i removed the if condition for the duration and removed the duration parameter, as well as the return statement.. ill update with new code

Comment: After you said you believed the duration always comes up false ,  i tried removing it as well as the return statement and it fixed it

Comment: _"I'm new to AS2"_ why not just learn AS3 once and for all? Later It also makes it easier to learn other languages too...

Comment: I Been Learning AS3 im 'Okay' at it , but the site i work for sometimes works with AS2 , so pretty much im making a loader that can change variables using Keyboard keys.. which i have one but i didnt make it so i want to make my own that works a bit better i updated this code to use an array instead of the i variable , it works but as soon as i load the game the keypress doesnt work..